# Nginx directory path as arguments

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use the location block in nginx to pass directory paths into an index.php as get arguments.

So the url `/api/arg1/arg2/` to be passed in as `/api/index.php?arg1=$1&$arg=2`

Here is my attempt below, someone can help with the regex or a better approach.

```
location ~ "^/api/(\w+)/([A-z,0-9].*)/$" {

    alias /api/index.php?arg1=$1&arg2=$2;

}
```

Side note, the arguments to be passed are a single word with no whitespaces being made up of numbers and letters, no other symbols needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
location ~ /api/(?P<arg1>\w+)/(?P<arg2>[A-z,0-9].*)/$" {

    rewrite "^.*$" /api/index.php?arg1=$arg1&arg2=$arg2;

}
```

If you are not worried of data in those args I would rather use

```
location ~ "/api/(?P<arg1>[^/]+)/(?P<arg2>[^/]+)/$" {

    rewrite "^.*$" /api/index.php?arg1=$arg1&arg2=$arg2;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After about five hours of messing around with nginx and getting redirect loops, file not found and config errors, I gave up and tried nodejs and managed to get what i was attempting after three minutes.    

```app.get("/api", handle);```
```app.get(/^\/api\/([a-z]+)\/$/, handle);```
```app.get(/^\/api\/([a-z]+)\/([a-z,0-9]+)\/$/, handle);```